# Resolve ViewModels in WinPhone 8.1, Prism and Unity

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, unity-container, prism

I am developing an Windows Phone 8.1 App with Prism for Windows Store Apps and Unity as IoC container. I got the basics working so far and the convention based resolving of View and ViewModel works so far.

For navigation I want to use a Drawer Layout (with a flyout menu) and display the selected models inside the `MainPage` (rather than navigating to pages).

So I have a `MainViewModel` (which gets correctly instantiated and assigned with `MainPage`, using a custom name convention). And I have a `DrawerViewModel`. The drawer is inside the `MainPage`, where also the other ViewModels shall be displayed.

My MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="StackExchangeReader.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:StackExchangeReader"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:m="using:StackExchangeReader.Models"
    xmlns:drawerLayout="using:DrawerLayout"
    xmlns:prism="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm"
    xmlns:designViewModels="using:StackExchangeReader.DesignViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance designViewModels:DrawerDesignViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

    <Grid x:Name="RootLayout">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Title Bar -->
        <Grid x:Name="TitleBar" Background="#00ADEF" Grid.Row ="0" Height="60">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Margin="5"  x:Name="DrawerIcon"  Grid.Column="0" Source="/Assets/drawer_icon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Tapped="DrawerIcon_Tapped" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"/>
        </Grid>
        <!-- Drawer Layout -->
        <drawerLayout:DrawerLayout Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="DrawerLayout">
            <Grid x:Name="MainFragment" Background="White">
                <!-- Main Content goes here -->
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="ListFragment" Background="#F4F4F4">
                <ListView DataContext="{Binding Sites}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </Grid>
        </drawerLayout:DrawerLayout>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The two things here to be notice are:

- MainFragment Grid, where the other ViewModels shall be displayed (i.e. after clicking an option in the Drawer Layout menu)
- ListFragment Grid, with the options the user can select

Now the actual problem/question:

Since Prism resolves ViewModels and Views by convention, of course...

1. ... it won't resolve the `DrawerViewModel`.
2. I can't instantiate it in XAML, cause it doesn't have a parameterless constructor and it has dependencies injected, so it's required that it's resolved via Unity.
3. Adding a property in `MainViewModel` could be possible, but then I'd need to inject it. While it would solve this one problem, it doesn't solve the problem that I also need to instantiate the Content (inside MainFragment) too. Also it's a bad idea to make ViewModels independent of each other. After all, MVVM should support loose coupling.
4. I also tried to define ViewModel dependency on the `MainPage` class, but Prism/Unity do not seem to be call this constructor (which Unity should do, if they were to be resolved via IoC/DI, because Unity chooses the constructor with the highest number of dependencies when it resolves the class)
5. I could also inject the IoC container into the MainViewModel, but this makes my ViewModel(s) depend on IoC. And passing IoC into ViewModel is a bad practice anyways.
6. I also considered using an abstract factory. This would avoid dependency on IoC container, but it feels like it only shifts the problem.

First things first: 
What would be the correct and elegant way to assign an instance of `DrawerViewModel` as `ListFragment`'s `DataContext`?

Could designing the `ListFragment` as an UserControl help allow me that the `DrawerViewModel` is correctly resolved and assigned to it? Anyone (preferably with Enterprise Business Application experience) having the same issues and a solution for this problem?

Just for the record, the two ViewModel classes.

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private INavigationService navigation;
    private IEventAggregator events;
    public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigation, IEventAggregator events)
    {
        this.navigation = navigation;
        this.events = events;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; } = "Example";
    private ViewModel selectedViewModel;

    public ViewModel SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set { SetProperty(ref selectedViewModel, value); }
    }

}
```

DrawerViewModel.cs

```
public class DrawerViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private ISiteService siteService;
    private IEventAggregator events;

    public DrawerViewModel(ISiteService siteService, IEventAggregator events)
    {
        this.siteService = siteService;
        this.events = events;

        sites = new ObservableCollection<Site>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Site> sites;
    public ObservableCollection<Site> Sites
    {
        get { return sites; }
    }
}
```